# How to prove that partial derivatives are zero for local max and min in 3d

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am confused on where to start on this proof. I read the proof for 2d and 1d(extreme value theorem) and it makes sense, but I cannot visualize it in 3d.

Show that if $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a local minimum or maximum point of $w=f(x,y,z)$, then $ \frac{\partial w}{\delta x} $,$ \frac{\partial w}{\delta y} $,$ \frac{\partial w}{\delta z} $ are all zero at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

let $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ be a minimum then $F(x)=f(x,y_0,z_0)$ has a minimum which means

$F'(x)=f_x(x,y,z)=0$